# How do I move the compass to the top of the screen in Fallout 76?

Tags: fallout-76

How do I move the compass to the top of the screen instead of the bottom in Fallout 76 on the PS4? Is there an option somewhere in the settings for it? The games I've played that actually have a compass always have it at the top so I keep looking to the top of the screen for it whenever I play. It's annoying when I don't find it there. I'd like it to be in the same place as it is in the rest of the games I play.

Alternatively, I'd rather it just be gone if I can't move it so that way I don't bother stopping to look for it. If I can't move it is there a way to just disable it entirely?